# JPA @JoinColumn not working properly with REST

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-security, joincolumn

Im learning Spring Security with REST, and I have 2 MySQL tables, one for users and one for authorities. The user_id from authorities table is foreign key for id from user table. I want to use these roles from authorities table with Spring Security for role-based authorisation. But I have a problem at the begining.

When I try to do a POST request to insert some data in these 2 tables the user_id from authorities table is NULL.

This is the code:

User entity:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class ApplicationUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="applicationUser", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Authorities> authorities;

    public ApplicationUser() {

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Authorities> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(List<Authorities> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

}
```

Authorities entity:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class Authorities {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String role;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, 
            CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private ApplicationUser applicationUser;

    public Authorities() {

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public ApplicationUser getApplicationUser() {
        return applicationUser;
    }

    public void setUser(ApplicationUser applicationUser) {
        this.applicationUser = applicationUser;
    }
}
```

REST Controller:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @GetMapping("/sign-up")
    public List<ApplicationUser> getUsers() {
        return applicationUserRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/sign-up")
    public void signUp(@RequestBody ApplicationUser user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        applicationUserRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

And when I try to do a POST request with this data:

```
{
   "username": "ion",
   "password": "1234",
   "authorities": [
   {
       "role": "ROLE_USER"
   }
   ]
}
```

the response is 200 but the MySQL tables look like this:

[image]

[image]

So, the user table looks fine, but the authorities table have the user_id cell NULL, and it should be 82.

I want to know how to resolve this problem and any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it with @JoinColumn(name="applicationuser_id")?

Comment: And your ApplicationUser entity should contain an addAuthorities and removeAuthorities method to maintain the relationship between the entities like mentioned in this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)